# Sending data via UDP from Android device to Windows server does not work on specific Windows machine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, udp

I am working on a project where an Android application sends data via UDP to a Unity application on a Windows server. I can confirm that it works correctly with two different Windows machines. On a third Windows machine, however, nothing is being received. 
What I have tried in detail:

- The Android device is connected to the Wifi hotspot of the respective Windows machine
- Therefore the server ip is always **192.168.137.1**, and I have tried different port numbers like **8888, 11000, 60320**
- All firewalls are disabled on the Windows machines

Could someone please give me a hint, what else I should try?

Comment: How do you handle multiple udp connections?

Comment: It is unnecessary to handle multiple connections, as the server simply listens on a certain port, where to potentially multiple clients could send. Actually there is always only one Android device at a time.